# Get full paper content from PubMed via API and list of IDs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pubmed

I'm hoping to query the PubMed API based on a list of paper IDs and return the title, abstract and content.

So far I have been able to do the first three things doing the following:

```
from metapub import PubMedFetcher

pmids = [2020202, 1745076, 2768771, 8277124, 4031339]
fetch = PubMedFetcher()

title_list = []
abstract_list = []
for pmid in pmids:
    article = fetch.article_by_pmid(pmid)
    abstract = article.abstract  # str
    abstract_list.append(abstract)
    title = article.title  # str
    title_list.append(title)
```

OR get the full paper content, but the query is based on keywords rather than IDs

```
email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
pubmed = PubMed(tool="PubMedSearcher", email=email)

## PUT YOUR SEARCH TERM HERE ##
search_term = "test"
results = pubmed.query(search_term, max_results=300)
articleList = []
articleInfo = []

for article in results:
# Print the type of object we've found (can be either PubMedBookArticle or PubMedArticle).
# We need to convert it to dictionary with available function
    articleDict = article.toDict()
    articleList.append(articleDict)

# Generate list of dict records which will hold all article details that could be fetch from PUBMED API
for article in articleList:
#Sometimes article['pubmed_id'] contains list separated with comma - take first pubmedId in that list - thats article pubmedId
    pubmedId = article['pubmed_id'].partition('\n')[0]
    # Append article info to dictionary
    articleInfo.append({u'pubmed_id':pubmedId,
                       u'title':article['title'],
                       u'keywords':article['keywords'],
                       u'journal':article['journal'],
                       u'abstract':article['abstract'],
                       u'conclusions':article['conclusions'],
                       u'methods':article['methods'],
                       u'results': article['results'],
                       u'copyrights':article['copyrights'],
                       u'doi':article['doi'],
                       u'publication_date':article['publication_date'],
                       u'authors':article['authors']})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to limit yourself to PubMed and text only, you could check out [paperscraper](https://pypi.org/project/paperscraper/). It scrapes publication data from PubMed, Google Scholar, and preprint servers and can even retrieve whole PDFs.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion) also, please show how to use it